# How can I measure the duration of a package execution?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have an SSIS job that I would like to run from a procedure, and then, using the job start and job end date execute a select statement.

Getting the job start time is easy- just save the current time from just before you call the job.

How can I get the end tim? Can I use `@endTime = GETDATE()`? Does starting the job wait for it to end ?

Is it true in general about calls inside SQL procedures?

EDIT:
As people asked, I wanted to call an SSIS job using this code, which I found [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2992/how-to-execute-an-integration-services-ssis-package-from-a-sql-server-stored-procedure/):

```
 declare @execution_id bigint
 exec ssisdb.catalog.create_execution 
 @folder_name = 'mssqltips'
 ,@project_name = 'exec-ssis-stored-proc-ssis-sample'
 ,@package_name = 'Sample.dtsx'
 ,@execution_id = @execution_id output
 exec ssisdb.catalog.start_execution @execution_id
```

Comment: So the question has nothing to do with stored procedures, it's about jobs. There's no `job run` stored procedure, there's a job *start* procedure, [sp_start_job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-start-job-transact-sql). It starts the job but doesn't wait for it to complete

Comment: Maybe he means calling xp_cmdshell with dtsx.exe inside?

Comment: The agent provides job status, run history and statistics. There's no reason to use `GETDATE()` to find how long a job took. Use [sp_job_history](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-help-jobhistory-transact-sql) or query the [sysjobhistory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql) table

Comment: @Xyzk, can you precise HOW would you like "to run from a procedure"?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I see your point, and I will investigate those options. That being said, I'm still curious to know if I could use this solution (even if it was not a very good one)

Comment: @Xyzk that's not a job. That's a *package* execution. Anyway, the SSIS database stores the execution history of packages as well

Comment: @Xyzk you can generate the package execution statements by selecting on the `Execute...` menu of a package, set the parameters you want and then click on the `Script` toolbar button instead of executing.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how to you run SSIS via SP. Is it a sql agent job or package execution (catalog)?

If you run it as package, it can be run synchronously or asynchronously.

If it is in asynchronous mode, SP just starts the SSIS package and doesn't wait.

IF it is in synchronous mode, it will wait.

The mode depends on SYNCHRONIZED parameter. This parameter should be set BEFORE execution starts, see the link below how to set it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-set-execution-parameter-value-ssisdb-database

If you run SQL job from SP and that job executes SSIS package, then SP does not wait, it just activates the SQL Agent Job.

Comment: I know, but Xyzk mentioned Package in the example, not job

Comment: The OP is asking how to measure an execution's duration. That is available from the execution history, no matter how the package is started.

Comment: Actually OP had multiple questions, one of them is "Does starting the job wait for it to end ? " and then example of package execution.  That's really confusing... I understand :)

Answer (score 1):

SSIS already logs package execution durations and events, including step durations. You don't need to use `GETDATE()`.

You can query the [catalog.executions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database) view of the SSISDB database to retrieve the execution status, start time and end time, eg:

```
select status, start_time, end_time,datediff(s,start_time,end_time) as duration
from catalog.executions
where execution_id = @execution_id
```

Or

```
select status, start_time, end_time, datediff(s,start_time,end_time) duration
from catalog.executions
where project_name = 'exec-ssis-stored-proc-ssis-sample'
      and  package_name = 'Sample.dtsx'
order by execution_id
```

for historical data

Comment: I think this answer should be combined with my answer. OP want to run SSIS AND get execution details from same SP. If it is a sql agent job, then SP should have some while loop with a delay with a condition to finish when the job stops. If it is a package, then see my answer, OP just needs to use GETDATE() with sync package execution

Comment: @Anton `GETDATE()` isn't needed when the actual duration is already available. In general, when you can access historical execution data, you no longer have to wait for execution to finish, you just read the historical view when you need to. Waiting would be useful  if the OP wanted to send an email after execution.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't mention this in question, because I wanted to avoid adding unnecessary information, but I do want to perform some basic operations AFTER the SSIS finishes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, historical data may not be available during runtime as the package was started and not yet completed. So SP needs to wait for SSIS completion if it requires to do something just after SSIS execution. Waiting mechanism depends on execution method (I mentioned it in the answer). Once the package is completed, GETDATE() is much faster and simpler than getting the stats from execution history, but if you need precise time, execution history is better.